# DateTime::modify returns wrong result

Tags: php

This code should show "2021-03-14 02:00:00" but it shows "2021-03-14 03:00:00":

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('2021-03-14 01:45:00');
$date->modify('15 minutes');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Any explanation for this? And more important, any workaround?

Comment: You forgot to account for Daylight savings time. That time is correct.

Comment: @JohnConde, makes sense. Thanks.